# How to translate 掩耳盗铃 into English?

Tags: translation, idioms

Preferably an idiom just as picturesque and succinct. Thanks.

Here's the original meaning:

> The expression 掩耳盗铃 comes from a story about a person who decided to
>   steal a bell. However, the bell was too heavy to carry and the thief
>   decided to break it into pieces. He was afraid the sound would attract
>   attention, so the thief blocked his ears and continued to smash the
>   bell believing that as long as he could not hear the bell's sound no
>   one else could either.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Oxford, CC-CEDICT, A Chinese-English dictionary all use the following idiom to define 掩耳盗铃:

> (to) bury one's head in the sand

The Free Dictionary defines it as:

> bury one's head in the sand and hide one's head in the sand; have one's head in the sand
>
> Fig. to ignore or hide from obvious signs of danger. (Alludes to an ostrich, which is believed incorrectly to hide its head in a hole in the ground when it sees danger.) *Stop burying your head in the sand. Look at the statistics on smoking and cancer.*

Like-wise Oxford Pocket also has:

> (to) bury one's head in the sand like an ostrich

It's not a perfect match, per se, but it's a pretty close English idiom.

Comment: Line Dict: bury one’s head in the sand
iciba： plug one's ears while stealing a bell ； bury one's head in the sand ； deceive oneself ； play the ostrich，

Answer (score 1):

No exact translation or idiom comes to mind, but I think a good expression/phrase would be to '**create a false sense of security**'.

The expression '**bury one's head in the sand**' suggests that one is aware of the danger but simply chooses to ignore or hide from it although the perceived level of risk/danger remains the same to the person, whereas when you create a false sense of security (whether you are consciously aware of it or not) then you do believe that the level of risk/danger has been reduced, as the person in the story did.

Answer (score 1):

Answer from [zdic.net](http://www.zdic.net/c/9/13c/302569.htm)

> plug one's ears while stealing a bell;deceive oneself as an ostrich that buries its head in the sand

Answer (score 0):

Blocking your own ears does not hide the sounds of your stealing a bell.

This is my own translation. Please comment.

Comment: Yes, that is what it means. I just wondered if there was a similar English idiom.

Comment: But if no one was around, then there was no sound. I digress. (Sure there was vibration, etc)

Comment: The sensation of the sound is the sound itself. The sensation of colour is the colour itself. There is no sound or colour outside the mind.

Comment: So, to be exact, your translation should be "blocking one's own ears does not prevent sound waves from reaching other ears."